# Do DSm(n) never be a prime?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Smarandache number (denoted as Sm(n)), is a number formed from concatenating the first n natural numbers. For example Sm(11)= $1234567891011$ (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmarandacheNumber.html). And now let Dsm(n) be a number formed from concatenating the first n natural numbers, and then arrange all digits on that concatenation into increasing digits (smallest to largest digits), so:

- Dsm(1)= $1$
- Dsm($2$)=$12$
- Dsm($3$)= $123$
- Dsm($10$)=$1123456789$
- Dsm($12$)=$11111223456789$
- Dsm($14$)= $111111122334456789$
- And So on...

Does Dsm(n) ever be a prime ? I've checked n up to $1800$, but I didn't find any primes. And I found that plenty of them divisible by $3$, by $7$ or by $11$, or by $47$, And some other small prime factors are also appear quite often, such as $37$ and $101$.

Comment: I am just running a PARI/GP program. According to it, such a number would have more than $8,000$ digits. Currently, I am at $n=2329$. Since the sequence grows relatively quickly, it could take very long until a prime occurs (if there is one).

Comment: @Peter, I found some semiprimes at n= $25$, $37$, $43$ : )

Comment: Since many of the numbers have no prime factor below $10^4$, I do not think that we can prove that every such number is composite by finding a set of primes "covering" all numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately, two semi-primes do not form a prime :)

Comment: Dsm(n) has fewer digits than Sm(n), since we can ignore all zeros.

Comment: Did you also try to sort the digits descending ? Maybe we get a prime this way.

Comment: @Peter, o yes I think that's also nice as well : )

Comment: The problem is boring with descending digits. Already $n=10$ gives a prime.

Comment: Descending would be looked like this 9876543210, I hate the fact that we must exclude all zeroes, in order for this descending mode to be a prime.

Comment: You forgot a $1$ and yes, we would have to exclude the zeros. Anyway, the problem you posted is much more interesting. We have to exclude the zeros also in the increasing case, but leading zeros are easier to handle with a program. However, it would not make a big difference.

Comment: $1$ has property that no prime numbers have it. For example $1+1+1+1+$..., can generate any primes, but we can't do that with for example $2+2+2+2...$ . Also $1$ to the power of any numbers is still equal $1$, surely no prime numbers have that properties.

Comment: The property $1^n=1$ is the most important reason to consider $1$ to be not prime. Otherwise, integer factorization would not be unique.

Comment: No primes upto $n=6,500$. A prime of the desired form must have more than $23,000$ digits.